# how to remove obsolete device and network entries? Device manager "uninstall" option has no effect

Tags: windows-8, drivers, network-adapter, device-manager

I am trying to remove a few "obsolete" things which annoy me (because I like to have everything cleen, working and not interferring with each other, fresh, etc..).

I tried looking for solutions without any help, so here I am to ask.

My first part is about removing obsolete networks, let me explain by showing the ipconfig output:

```
C:\windows\system32>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter LAN:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c129:8d57:bbd1:3564%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.254

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home

C:\windows\system32>
```

Specificalyy the first two adapter entries annoy me because the adapters are not visible in the network connection menu (invisible folder / file visibility set to "show"):

[image]

And here is the second problem altogether with the first one:

[image]

No matter what I click/do, Uninstall option has no effect on the multiplexor driver. (bridging stuff, right?)

I really want to remove the Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection entries and the adapter multiplexor stuff but it's impossible? Why is this? How can I remove them anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel --> Programs and Features ---> Turn Windows Features On or Off
and try to uninstall the Hyper-V.

Comment: Ihave the normal windows 8, there is no Hyper-V service there :/ (I oncen eeded it but windows told me it's only forwindows 8 pro / enterprise, so I uninstalled windows phone SDK)

Comment: I also checked service manager and all hyper-v services are stopped.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be necessary to uninstall Hyper-V.

Simply go back to `devmgmt.msc` and click *View* → *Show hidden devices*. Click *Scan for hardware changes* and then it should make it a non-hidden device. Then you can uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a device fully, the option box for *Delete the driver software for this device* must also be ticked when uninstalling from Device Manager.

- Simply uninstalling a device via Device Manager, *without ticking the aforementioned box*, only temporarily removes the device, as it's driver files are still present.  Due to this, the device will auto-reinstall upon either choosing *Scan for hardware changes* in Device Manager or rebooting the OS.